# How to Display The last 4 digit of numbers and replace the rest of the number with XXXXXXXXX's

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How to displays the last four digits of the
Numbers in this format: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1234. In other words, use Xs for the first
12 digits of the card number and actual numbers for the last four digits of the number.
Thank YOu

Comment: The question seems to start in the middle of a sentence. Please write more clearly. Also see [ask] for the way to ask a good question.

Comment: Does it have to work for 15-digit AMEX payment card numbers too?

Comment: Recommend avoiding storing credit number, or store them as the masked value.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that you can use to make this job: you can pass to this function any number, the function calculates the modulo 10000 class of the number (i.e. the rest of the division by 10000) in other words the last four digits of your number. Then the function concatenates XXXX-XXXX-XXXX- and zeros as needed.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION N_CREDIT_CARD 
(NUMBER INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(19)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE NUM INT;
  SET NUM=NUMBER%10000;
  RETURN (CASE WHEN NUM < 10 THEN CONCAT('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-000', CAST(NUM AS CHAR(1)))
               WHEN NUM < 100 THEN CONCAT('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-00', CAST(NUM AS CHAR(2)))
               WHEN NUM < 1000 THEN CONCAT('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0', CAST(NUM AS CHAR(3)))
               ELSE CONCAT('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-',CAST(NUM AS CHAR(4))) END);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```